# Create variable or call method in java

Tags: java, variables, methods

I am learning java programming.
When I went through the class examples, I saw below code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in)
```

I understand that it declares a Scanner variable input, but I wonder why I should declare such variable but not use this function by calling method in class Scanner directly?

Answer (score 4):

You should declare a `Scanner` as a variable because the `Scanner` class is not static.

Let's break down the assignment:

1. First, you have `Scanner input`. This indicates that a variable of name `input` will be allocated as a `Scanner`.
2. Then, you have `new Scanner`, which tells Java that you are creating a new `Object` of type `Scanner` to be stored in field `input`.
3. Then, you are calling the constructor of the scanner class. More specifically, you are calling it with the value: `System.in`.

It's the third step which is critical here. Since you are new, if you do not understand the `static` modifier, I would look that up before trying to process this.

Your new Scanner has one argument in its constructor: `InputStream`. An `InputStream` is an interface to, for instance, a keyboard. Here's the reason why you cannot call `Scanner.next()`: What if you want to have two different input streams?

By creating a variable `input`, you're storing the `Scanner` *specific to System.in* within that variable. If you have a file, you may want another Scanner for its InputStream (though files aren't really read that way, you get the point.)

If Scanner's functions were static, you would only be able to have one Scanner. Which would mean limiting the user to only one input stream via Scanner.

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with the wording of step one, since it doesn't create a Scanner.

Comment: Ah, whoops. My mistake, fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

> why I should declare such variable but not use this function by calling method in class Scanner directly?

Only a `static` method might be called like you suggest.  Most `Scanner` methods worth mentioning, are not `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the statement - 
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

We can break it into two portion -
**(1)** A reference named `input` is created to hold any variable of type `Scanner` at left side of the assignment.
**(2)** An object of type `Scanner` is instantiated the the right side of the assignment. And finally the instance/object of type `Scanner` is assigned with the newly created variable.

Now come to your questions -

> why I should declare such variable but not use this function by
>   calling method in class Scanner directly?

Because in `Scanner` class there is no such method that returns a scanner type variable to assigned with the newly created variable `input`. More over to call a function inside a class without creating object of the class the method should be `static.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read up a little bit more about OOP. But essentially what you are asking about being able to directly call methods of a class, is called static methods of a class. They are not bound to any particular instance. Static methods have no knowledge of any instance specific data. In this case the InputStream passed in to the constructor.

Since I don't know what particular Scanner class you are referring to, I assume the people who wrote the class felt it was useful to have access to the InputStream as a data member for the functions to act upon. Therefore it was designed that way.

Generally speaking in OOP this is how things are designed. Objects are instantiated with data and functions are called on the objects. The use of static methods arguably breaks OOP architecture to some extent.

I hope that clarifies things somewhat.